# Disabling Multipart Caching in CXF jax-rs

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I [posted](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/Disable-multipart-caching-in-temp-files-on-the-server-stream-straight-out-the-socket-td5719255.html) this question to the CXF list, without any luck. So here we go. I am trying to upload large files to a remote server (think of them virtual machine disks). So I have a restful service that accepts upload requests. The handler for the upload looks like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/doupload")
public Response receiveStream(MultipartBody multipart) {
    List<Attachment> allAttachments = body.getAllAttachments();
    Attachment att = null;
    for (Attachment b : allAttachments) {
        if (UPLOAD_FILE_DESCRIPTOR.equals(b.getContentId())) {
            att = b;
        }
    }
    Assert.notNull(att);
    DataHandler dh = att.getDataHandler();
    if (dh == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    try {
        InputStream is = dh.getInputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
        int n;
        OutputStream os = getOutputStream();
        while ((n = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
            os.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        ResponseBuilder rb = Response.status(HTTP_CREATED);
        return rb.build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Got exception=", e);
        throw new WebApplicationException(HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        log.error("Got exception=", e);
        throw new WebApplicationException(HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR);
    } finally {}

}
```

The client for this code is fairly simple:

```
public void sendLargeFile(String filename) {
    WebClient wc = WebClient.create(targetUrl);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
    Response r = wc.post(new Attachment(Constants.UPLOAD_FILE_DESCRIPTOR,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, is));
}
```

The code works fine in terms of functionality. In terms of performance, I noticed that before my handler (receiveStream() method) gets the first byte out of the stream, the whole stream actually gets persisted into a temporary file (using a CachedOutputStream). Unfortunately, this is not acceptable for my purposes.

- My handler simply passes the incoming bytes to a backend storage system (virtual machine disk repository), and waiting for the whole disk to be written to a cache only to be read again takes a lot of time, tying up a lot of resources, and reducing throughput.
- There is a cost associated with writing the blocks and reading them again, since the app is running in the cloud, and the cloud provider charges per block read/written.
- Since every byte is written to the local disk, my service VM must have enough disk space to accommodate the total sizes of all the streams being uploaded (i.e., if I have 10 uploads of 100GB each, I must have 1TB of disk just to cache the content). That again is extra money, as the size of the service VM grows dramatically, and the cloud provider charges for the provisioned disk size as well.

Given all of this, I am looking for a way to use the HTTP InputStream (or as close to it as possible) to read the attachment directly from there and handle it afterwards. I guess the question translates into one of: 
- Is there a way to tell CXF not do caching
- OR - is there a way to pass CXF an output stream (one I write) to use, rather than using CachedOutputStream

I found a similar question [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/200907.mbox/%3C24677330.post@talk.nabble.com%3E). The resolution says use CXF 2.2.3 or later, I am using 2.4.4 (and tried with 2.7.0) with no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's logically not possible (neither in CXF or anywhere else). You're calling `getAllAttachements()`, which means that the server should collect information about them from the HTTP input stream. It means that the entire stream has to go into memory for [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) parsing.

In your case you should work directly with the stream, and do the MIME parsing yourself:

```
public Response receiveStream(InputStream input) {
```

Now you have full control of the input and can consume it into memory byte-by-byte.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are onto something. However, please note that by the time the it comes into my handler where I call the getAllAttachments(), all the message is already read and buffered. You did give me an idea though. I think it is the MIME type causing this behavior. I will try to see whether I can use another MIME type that hands an InputStream to the handler. Thanks again, it gives me something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing the problem in an unelegant way, but it works, so I wanted to share my experience. Please do let me know if there are some "standard" or better ways.

Since I am writing the server side, I knew I was accessing all the attachments in the order they were sent, and process them as they are streamed in. So, to reflect that behavior of the handler method (receiveStream() method above), I created a new annotation on the server side called "@SequentialAttachmentProcessing" and annotatated my above method with it.

Also, wrote a subclass of Attachment, called SequentialAttachment that acts like a linked list. It has a skip() method that skips over the current attachment, and when an attachment ends, hasMore() method tells you whether there is another one.

Then I wrote a custom multipart/form-data provider which behaves as follows: If the target method is annotated as above, handle the attachment, otherwise call the default provider to do the handling. When it is handled by my provider, it always returns at most one attachment. Hence it could be misleading to a non-suspecting handling method. However, I think it is acceptable since the writer of the server must have annotated the method as "@SequentialAttachmentProcessing" and therefore must know what that entails.

As a result the implementation of the receiveStream() method is now something like:

```
@POST
@SequentialAttachmentProcessing
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/doupload")
public Response receiveStream(MultipartBody multipart) {
    List<Attachment> allAttachments = body.getAllAttachments();
    Assert.isTrue(allAttachments.size() <= 1);
    if (allAttachment.size() > 0) {
        Attachment head = allAttachments.get(0);
        Assert.isTrue(head instanceof SequentialAttachment);
        SequentialAttachment att = (SequentialAttachment) head;
        while (att != null) {
            DataHandler dh = att.getDataHandler();
            InputStream is = dh.getInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
            int n;
            OutputStream os = getOutputStream();
            while ((n = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                os.write(buf, 0, n);
            }
            if (att.hasMore()) {
                att = att.next();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this solved my immediate problem, I still believe there has to be a standard way of doing this. I hope this helps someone.