# file upload with REST: using InputStream instead of loading all to RAM

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, wildfly, resteasy

I hava a single page web application (Angular 1), where I need to upload large files to our Java backend.
The backend is running on Wildfly 8.2.1 - thus, RESTeasy is the JAX-RS implementation used.

I use the following code on web application side: http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/ -> note the progress indication...

On backend side, I have the following code (just as prove of concept):

```
@POST
@Path("uploadfile")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response upload(MultipartFormDataInput multipart) throws IOException
{

    try (InputStream in = multipart.getFormDataPart("file", InputStream.class, null);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myfile"))
    {
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(buff)) != -1)
        {
            fos.write(buff, 0, count);
        }
    }
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

What I observe is that if I set a break point on the first line (`try`), it will get hit *after* the upload progress in the Web has reached 100%. I then can close the browser (while staying in breakpoint), continue the java part and it will still save the file correctly.

This means that Wildfly catchs all data to RAM first, before the JAX-RS endpoint method is called? I think so, otherwise, how could this behaviour be explained. But why? How could this be changed to real streaming? I like to see a direct coupling of the web progress bar and the loop of where the file is stored - so I imagine that if I set a break point in the while loop, it should pause the progressbar in the browser...

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596857/disabling-multipart-caching-in-cxf-jax-rs

Comment: You sure it's not writing it to a temp file instead of storing it in memory?

Comment: @Karl Nicholas: Thanks for the link; you could post it as answer (with a short summary) and I would accept it as answer and vote up!

Comment: @peeskillet: You are right, after some tests I confirm it is stored as a temp file.

Comment: So, it's not a problem if the file is being written to a temp file then?